# set sound stop if click another click button sound are start

Tags: java, android

First, Just want you the know that im following this site a long time and i always enjoy to read here and see the brilliant smart people here :).

i had a problem with my new app project (build it for my kids) and i hope somone will help me with it.

on my app , i had a nine diffrents buttons.
for any button i had diffrent sound.

if you press the "bird button" then you can hear a bird voice twitt,
if you press the "dog button" you will hear a dog voice... 
i set sound for all the nine buttons and when i press one of them i can hear the sound nice as i want.

but(!), if i press  one of the button and imidiattly after that i press on another botton,i hear the voice together (for exsmple if i press dog button and one second after the i press the cat button, i hear the dog and the cat voise togther..)

jost wondring if you can help me so set it up.. if i press one butten i can hear a button voice. but if i press another button, the previusly sound will stop (not pause- stop) and i can hear only the last voice button that i press.
public class animals extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_animals );

    final MediaPlayer birdMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bird);
    final MediaPlayer catMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cat);
    final MediaPlayer chickenMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chicken);
    final MediaPlayer cowMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cow);
    final MediaPlayer dogMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dog);
    final MediaPlayer elephentMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.elephent);
    final MediaPlayer horseMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.horse);
    final MediaPlayer sheepMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sheep);
    final MediaPlayer wolfMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.wolf);



    final Button Btnbird = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btnbird );
    final Button Btncat = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btncat );
    final Button Btnchicken = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btnchicken );
    final Button Btncow = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btncow );
    final Button Btndog = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btndog );
    final Button Btnhelf = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btnhelf );
    final Button Btnhurse = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btnhurse );
    final Button Btnsheep = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btnsheep );
    final Button Btnwolf = (Button)this.findViewById( R.id.Btnwolf );


    Btnbird.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            birdMP.start();


        }

    } );

    Btncat.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            birdMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            catMP.start();



        }
    } );

    Btnchicken.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            chickenMP.start();

        }
    } );
    Btncow.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            cowMP.start();

        }
    } );
    Btndog.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            dogMP.start();

        }
    } );
    Btnhelf.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            elephentMP.start();

        }
    } );
    Btnhurse.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            horseMP.start();

        }
    } );
    Btnsheep.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            wolfMP.stop();
            sheepMP.start();

        }
    } );
    Btnwolf.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            catMP.stop();
            chickenMP.stop();
            birdMP.stop();
            dogMP.stop();
            elephentMP.stop();
            horseMP.stop();
            sheepMP.stop();
            cowMP.stop();
            wolfMP.start();

        }
    } );


    findViewById( R.id.back ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(animals.this,MainActivity.class  );
            startActivity( intent );

        }


    } );


}
```

}

Comment: I think you could try to make an array of your buttons. That way, you could do a loop over all buttons to stop them. I'm not sure if it could work that way ... anyway, I'm interested in a solution for this kind of problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like `stopSound()`, which stops all the sound by calling `stop()`.

Example: `wolfMP.stop()`

Call `stopSound()` before you want to start the next sound.

Comment: Unfortunately, without success.